# Close menu event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu plugin in jQuery.
The menu is closed only when i click the inner circle of it...

> www.tranceil.fm -> click the headphones

I want to close the menu by clicking anywhere, not just the inner circle

the header code is this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){


                var pieMenu = jQuery('#promo').pieMenu({icon : [
                        { 
                            path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/winamp.png",
                            alt  : "Winamp",
                            fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.pls';return false}
                        },  { 
                            path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/vlc.png",
                            alt  : "VLC Media Player",
                            fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.pls';return false}  
                        },{ 
                            path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/QuickTime.png",
                            alt  : "Quick Time Player",
                            fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.qtl';return false}
                        },{ 
                            path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/WMP.png",
                            alt  : "Windows Media Player",
                            fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.asx';return false}
                        },{ 
                            path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/popup.png",
                            alt  : "נגן Popup",
                            fn   : function(){jQuery("#popupplay").click();return false}
                        },{ 
                            path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/iTunes.png",
                            alt  : "iTunes",
                            fn   : function(){alert('...בקרוב');return false}
                        }],
                    beforeMenuOpen: function(){
                        jQuery('<div id="shadow"></div>').css(
                        {
                            'position':'fixed',
                            'background-color':'#000000',
                            'opacity': 0.6,
                            'width':'100%',
                            'height':'100%',
                            'z-index' :999,
                            'top':0,
                            'left':0
                        }).appendTo('body');
                    },
                    beforeMenuClose: function(){
                        jQuery('#shadow').remove();
                    }
                });

                jQuery('#promo').click(function(){
                if(jQuery('#'+pieMenu.id).css('display') != 'block') //if jpie is not visible
                pieMenu.initMenu(760,150);

                })
            });

        </script>
```

The click event in the JS file ->

```
//click event
            jQuery('#'+idCore).live({
                click: function() {
                    if(closable)
                        removeMenu();
                },
                contextmenu:function(e){
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                }
            })
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you facing an issue or just asking for an opinion?

Comment: I want to close the menu by clicking anywhere, not just the inner circle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to remove the `pie0` div and the `shadow` div when the shadow is clicked, because they're being entirely generated/re-generated whenever they are brought on/back to the screen.

So just add this:

```
$('#shadow').on('click', function(event){
    $('#pie0').remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**Update**: I just realized: because shadow is added dynamically after a user-event, and not present on documentready, you need to define it by attaching it to the body element, and delegating to a click on the shadow element, like this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'shadow', function(event){
    $('#pie0').remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Hey Faust thanx for the reply. it didn't work.. i also tried changing the $ to jQuery

Comment: is it possible you missed a token m8? i get ILLEGAL token

Comment: I had an extra quote-mark in there before `function` when I submitted the edit just now, but syntax highlighting flagged it for me after the post, and I've removed it. Try again.

Comment: Before i insert it again, would you recomend to replace it with the beforemenuclose paramater like this? -> beforeMenuClose: function(){
                        jQuery('body').on('click', 'shadow', function(event){
                        jQuery('#pie0').remove();
                        jQuery(this).remove();
                    
                    });

Comment: No -- what's in beforeMenuClose only gets fired once pieMenu already receives an instruction to close. You could define it within beforeMenuOpen, but then you'd be re-defining it everytime, before the menu opens. Best to define it on documentready, I think.

Comment: Like so? <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery('body').on('click', 'shadow', function(event){
    jQuery('#pie0').remove();
    jQuery(this).remove();
});
                
                var pieMenu = jQuery('#promo').pieMenu({icon : [
                        { 
                            path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/winamp.png",
                            alt  : "Winamp",
                            fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://........

Comment: Looks like it should work. Hard to tell with the code all jammed into a comment. It shouldn't matter whether you have the new code before or after setting the pieMenu.

Comment: Ah, doh!  `... . on('click', 'shadow', func ....` should be `... . on('click', '#shadow', func ....`   (forgot the hash -- sorry!)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close it by clicking anywhere:

```
$(document).live({
    ....
});
```

The problem that you will face here is that this click will cause other clicks also to happen. For example, if the user clicks on some link or something, he will be redirected and also the menu will be closed. Moreover, since `document` is a top level element, events will never propogate **FROM** it, they will always propogate **TO** it. Even if such was not the case, `live` works in a way such that it handles events once they have propagated to the top

What you can do is, set it up in capture mode:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if(closeable) {
        removeMenu();
        event.stopPropogation();
    }
}, true);
```

The `true` parameter at the end sets this event listener in the `capturing` mode, which will cause it to call the event handler of the highest order ancestor there is, which will be there for document. After calling that event, the event is then bubbled to the target. And within document's event handler, if we consume an event (we shall do it ONLY and ONLY if closeable is set), then we don't propagate it at all.

Comment: I see...only thing is, where do i insert your latest code entry? do i replace that with something?